# Elasticsearch do not want to accept null for date

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, indexing

My Index looks like:

```
      "valid_to": {
        "type": "date",
        "null_value": "null",
        "format": "date_time"
      }
```

But when I want to index my data and some data does not have a date I get error exception instead to accept it as null.

```
"reason":"failed to parse [valid_from]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Invalid format: \"\""}}
```

Any hint, please?

Comment: If this is json, why put the null in ""?

Comment: This is part of the elasticsearch (GET my_index_read_model/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the [`ignore_malformed`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#date-params) parameter (false by default), like this:

```
  "valid_to": {
    "type": "date",
    "null_value": "null",
    "format": "date_time",
    "ignore_malformed": true
  }
```

Or make sure to either always send a valid date or null